# "E_INVALID_HASHER_DRIVER: Hash driver bcryptsu does not exists. > More details: https://err.sh/adonisjs/errors/E_INVALID_HASHER_DRIVER"

Tags: adonis.js

My password are not encrypt.
E_INVALID_HASHER_DRIVER: Hash driver bcryptsu does not exists. > More details: https://err.sh/adonisjs/errors/E_INVALID_HASHER_DRIVER"

Comment: please add more details in description.

Comment: You need to read this one [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i will try in next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that `bcryptsu` exists.

Change your `.env` like:

```
...
HASH_DRIVER=bcrypt
```